# Text line in UITextView is cut the middle

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a `UITextView` set to plain and with 20px leading, trailing, bottom and top constraints.

The problem is the text is cut in the middle of a text line. 
The `UITextView` height and width are as they should be.

I started the project on Xcode 8 / Swift 3 and upgraded to Xcode 9 / Swift 4 and there is no difference (not that I was expecting it to get fix out of the blue).

[image: In Xcode]

[image: In simulator 1]

[image: In simulator 2]

The `UITextView` is the red rectangular. As you can see, it looks OK in Xcode.

I also have another 4 identical view controllers but this is the only one with this issue.

Any ideas? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Is this a UITextField or UITextView?

Comment: Why don't you let it *`UITextView`* instead of `UITextField`?

Comment: My bad, it a UITextView, not TextField.

Comment: @AhmadF - it is a UITextView. My bad.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, are editing its `contentSize` property?

Comment: Are you getting this issue during run time? I mean the last screenshots are taken from a simulator/device, correct? And you're only experiencing such issue in Xcode 9? hmmm.

Comment: @AhmadF - Nope. The VC is as static as it gets. The text is added from within Xcode (not programmatically) and the size is set using the margin constraints.

Comment: @Glenn - Yes, during run time but not only on Xcode 9. It also happened on Xcode 8 and on iOS 10/11 devices. I just left it like this for a while because it wasn't very important compared to other tasks.

Comment: Can you remove that `UITextView` and add a new one instead? I doubt that this will help, but have you tried cleaning your project and your build? Cmd+Shift+K and Cmd+Shift+AltOption+K.

Comment: @Glenn - I tried cleaning the project as well as removing the UITextView. The only thing I haven't tried is to remove the VC entirely and add a new one.

Comment: Hmmm.. comments is getting longer. Three more tips, use Xcode's view debugger, and try to uncheck the `clears graphics context` in attributes inspector, restart Xcode. These might be irrelevant to others but these are the things I would do if I were to experience such an issue. Hoping for others to answer this. I'm interested too.

Comment: If you can't find problems with the `UITextView` check if you're possibly implementing any extensions where you may be overriding `contentSize`, `sizeThatFits`, etc. I've had it once, it drove me nuts until I figured it out.

Comment: @AuRis - It was one of the first things I checked and no, unfortunately.

Comment: @Glenn - Well, I ended up deleting the VC and creating it all over again. I also used the same VC class. Now it seems to be working, Still not sure what could've caused this issue. Truth be told I've had some other strange issues with this project. In some screens the green text was always displayed as blue and orange text as red. Had to recreate the VC there as well...

Comment: Good to know that you've solved it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up deleting the VC and creating it all over again. I also used the same VC class. Now it seems to be working.